# Mysql query optimization with cases

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the query from **vw_pharmacy_contracts** view that i neet to optimize:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_pharmacy_contracts_per_period;
CREATE VIEW vw_pharmacy_contracts_per_period AS 
SELECT 
inn_prod.pharmacy_inn, 
inn_prod.period_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN marketing_contract_types_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS zentiva_marketing_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN marketing_contract_types_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS direct_marketing_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN marketing_contract_types_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rx_marketing_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN marketing_contract_types_id = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS diabetes_marketing_count,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT inn_prod.marketing_contract_types_id SEPARATOR ',') AS CHAR (63) CHARSET UTF8) AS marketing_contract_types,
CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT marketing_contracts.type_name SEPARATOR ',') AS CHAR (255) CHARSET UTF8) AS marketing_contract_types_name
FROM inn_to_marketing_products inn_prod 
LEFT JOIN marketing_contract_types marketing_contracts ON (inn_prod.marketing_contract_types_id = marketing_contracts.id)
group by inn_prod.pharmacy_inn, inn_prod.period_id;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_pharmacy_contracts;
CREATE VIEW vw_pharmacy_contracts AS 
SELECT pharma_state.period_id, pharma_state.pharmacy_id, pharma.inn,
       case when cnt.zentiva_marketing_count > 0 then true else false end as zentiva_marketing, 
       case when cnt.direct_marketing_count > 0 then true else false end as direct_marketing,  
       case when cnt.rx_marketing_count > 0 then true else false end as rx_marketing,
       case when cnt.diabetes_marketing_count > 0 then true else false end as diabetes_marketing,
       case when (cnt.marketing_contract_types IS NOT NULL) then true else false end as has_contract,
             cnt.marketing_contract_types AS marketing_contract_types,
       cnt.marketing_contract_types_name AS marketing_contract_types_name
FROM pharmacy_state pharma_state
left join pharmacy pharma on pharma.id = pharma_state.pharmacy_id
left join vw_pharmacy_contracts_per_period cnt on cnt.pharmacy_inn = pharma.inn and cnt.period_id = pharma_state.period_id;
```

[explain from vw_pharmacy_contracts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qojy1.png)

[explain from vw_pharmacy_contracts_per_period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzwax.png)

Here responce of **vw_pharmacy_contracts**:
[responce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i4qb.png). Durection of query is like 21-23 sec.I need to speed up one of these views. If anyone helps i will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `vw_pharmacy_contracts_per_period` is calculating the data over and over.  That is, every time you use it, it is scanning all the data and coming up with the same results.  Meanwhile, it takes a non-trivial amount of time.

So, let's build a "Summary Table" that contains the *results* of that view.  It would probably have `PRIMARY KEY(pharmacy_inn, period_id)`.

Is a "period" one day?  Every night(?) compute just the day's(?) data and add it to the Summary table.  After you have that well in hand, we can see if the second view can be optimized.

More on [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Meanwhile, please use `JOIN` unless you really need the righthand table to be optional, and hence can justify `LEFT`.